# Better performance for changing top / left of many elements: JQuery or Pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, performance

Question about the actual benefit of pure of vanilla js vs. jQuery. I have read many forums and articles on the advantages of pure js or vanilla js vs. jQuery but I'm wondering if it would actually help my specific situation and it's worth going back and rewriting the code.

I have a webpage with about 20 elements with images, and when a user clicks a button all 20 of those elements slide to the left, and when the user clicks again they slide back. Currently I'm using `$('#elementID').css({top: x, left: y});` for each element in the function to change it. Would converting it to `document.getElementById(elementID).cssText({top: x, left: y});` OR `document.getElementById(elementID).style.top = x; document.getElementById(elementID.style.left = y;` actually make a noticeable performance change?

What if I expect a user to frequently trigger this, would it make a difference in performance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you currently experience performance problems with this at all? If not, what are you trying to optimise? If so, then you better [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: no it doesnt make any noticable change as it is run client sided not server sided. The only difference in speed is by the bandwidth. as you save a few bytes you might load the webside a milisecond (literally) faster.

Comment: Both do the same thing and there is little to no chance for a performance win here. Though there is a gain in using the `transform` property instead of `top` and `left`.

Comment: JQuery is nothing more that Vanilla JavaScript that someone else wrote. I can't imagine it would ever be more performant than Vanilla JavaScript assuming that you wrote performant JavaScript (we all know that you can write crappy code in any language).

Comment: @EmielZuurbier What would I gain by using the transform property instead?

Comment: CSS Transformations can utilize the graphics processor of a machine while straight JavaScript doesn't.

Comment: @VLAZ sometimes when I trigger the slide it doesn't move as fast as other times, and I still have more interactivity I want to add. Also my CPU % use meter jumps by like 20% when I click the button, and compared to other sites I've tested it seemed rather high. Maybe I'm confusing two issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of 20 images and "one time" calling - not really, but when you have to work with a lot of DOM manipulations - difference can be very huge.

I like to use https://jsbench.me/ to bench JavaScript.

[image]

Comment: Well, this is sort of my point. You aren't comparing apples to apples. JQuery is creating a custom array-like object and endowing it with custom properties and the JavaScript is not.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But in any case, just to apply styles from an object, but not from "direct setters" jQuery will do a lot of overhead there, starts from wrapping dom-elements, parsing object, applying styles, etc... A lot of work under the hood anyway, IMHO

Comment: @Denis thank you for the screenshot, it definitely makes me reconsider using jQuery going forward and I'll certainly be using that site!

Comment: @sychordCoder You're welcome  Anyway, jQuery still be a good library when you need just to write some lines of code to make them work even in IE 11, without any bundlers, npm libraries, etc, also tons of carousel/sliders/modal libraries exists for jQuery (tbh, even for React/Vue/Angular too ) Anyway, all depends of your needs and how much time/money you can invest in a project 

Comment: @ScottMarcus I changed my left positioning change to transform: translate and it immediately improved. I did half the elements and it was clear they were moving faster. Excited to see if removing jQuery can make it even faster/smoother.

Comment: @Denis I'm still going to use jQuery for parts of this site where I need to build a bunch of html elements using js and that all happens on load only so I'm going to leave that as is since it makes the code easier to read/understand.